# What is the process to view associated table/entity in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I would like to view the associated table which holds details from Marketing/contacts in Dynamics CRM.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Marketing" menu navigate to "Marketing Lists."